# Transmitting the location of Physical process to Application module in Castalia

Tags: omnet++

So when a physical process calculates the return value using the following function:

`retVal TargetPhysicalProcess::calculateScenarioReturnValue(const double &x_coo,
                             const double &y_coo, const simtime_t &stime)`

along with the value I am also sending the location of physical process taken from current snapshot. When the sensor manager receives the reply it extracts the data from  `PhysicalProcessMessage` and stores it in a `SensorReadingMessage` to send to Application module.

So when the data is extracted from `PhysicalProcessMessage`,I extract the location as well and when I have to store data in `SensorReadingMessage`, I can't do that because there are no `readingMsg->setXcoor` and `readingMsg->setYcoor` functions.

What can be the possible solution?

Comment: I noticed that you are asking a lot of questions on Castalia lately, without studying existing material first. This question for example shows a basic misunderstanding on the model of physical process. Stackoverflow is not a personal tutor, and I cannot keep answering questions that show a lack of effort to learn the basics of Castalia first.

Comment: I have studied the code of physical process and i have modified the calculateScenariofunction. 
I am working on my thesis right now, I developed the algorithms first and then studied castalia and that is why I am changing some things according to my algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location you are referring to is **already known by the node**. It is **the location of the node**! The various modules within the node already have access to this info (through the MobilityManager).

There is no "location of the physical process". The physical process happens all over the space. It is the node who is asking for a specific value in space and time that it has to provide the location and time moment.

Comment: Since I am working on a target tracking application, I am working on retracing the path at sink node. I have changed the code of calculatescenario function and now its not all over the space.
By location i mean x and y value of a snapshot.
the snapshots are representing the path of target hence I am transmitting x and y values to application module.

Comment: You seem utterly confused about what `x_coo` and `y_coo` are in the function call. I already explained some basics, and the manual also has information on the basics of phy process and overall modelling. Study it. I cannot stress this enough. As a side node, sending back to the node the location of the target seems like a horrible way to simulate any tracking system. If you do not understand this, I suggest you consult with your advisor.